# Is entropy is a kind of energy? Is entropy be categorized into thermal energy or work?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

1. I know that entropy is measure of disorder... I know that in Gibbs free energy, entropy is TREATED as energy...but I feel confused whether entropy is energy or not, by definition of entropy.
2. If entropy is not a kind of energy, then the question ends. However, if the entropy is really energy, then applying thermodynamics 1st law to entropy, should entropy be categorized as work or thermal energy, s.t. 1st law of thermodynamics valids?

Comment: Entropy is not energy. One can see it from the units: in the SI system, the unit is joules per kelvin, not joules.

Comment: “*in Gibbs free energy, entropy is TREATED as free energy*” How so? The Gibbs free energy G = U + PV - TS. Appearing in the definition does not make them equivalent; in fact, one increases as the other decreases, all else held constant.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Why not post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Entropy is a state variable. It is related but it’s not the same as energy. Later, it turned out that you can understand entropy in terms of disorder. Given a certain macrostate (temperature, volume and pressure) there can be many many microstates (position and velocity of each individual particle in the gas). The more microstates correspond to one macrostate, the higher the entropy of that macrostate.

Answer (score 2):

You can see from the definition of entropy
$$
S=k_B \log W
$$
that it is **not** energy: $W$ is the *number* of microstates, hence $\log W$ is just a pure (dimensionless) number, consequently dimension of entropy is equal to that of $k_B$ which is *energy per temperature*. Therefore entropy is neither energy nor temperature: it is a new independent concept.